# How to ignore line breaks in windows version gnu grep?

Tags: windows, regex, grep

windows xp, 
gnu grep from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

I have file with line breaks:

```
test 
  123
```

I try to use gnu grep for finding this file by regexp pattern  `"test.*\n*.*12"`

```
grep -G "test.*\n*\.*12" C:\myfile_with_linebreaks.txt
```

but no success.

Which parameters or regexp pattern i need use to find string with line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use `[^\0]` (every character but NUL), since most strings don't contain the NUL character.  Otherwise, I assemble a character group that includes `.` *and* `\n`:

```
grep -G "test[.\n]*12" C:\
```

If, on the contrary, you want exactly one line break between test and 123, I’d use the non-greedy `*` operator:

```
grep -G "test.*?\n.*?12" C:\
```

The `?` question mark after the `*` operator will restrain that operator.  Without `?`, it will carry on until it finds the last following match; with `?` it will stop at the first following match.

Also, it might be that you explicitly need to enable POSIX extended regular expressions, with the -E switch:

```
grep -E "test.*?\n.*?12" C:\
```

Comment: I tried this option (-z, --null-data every character but NUL), but disadvantage that all file content treated as single line. My files really big, so this options don't satisfate me

Comment: Ah, wait.  You actually want exactly one line break between test and 123?  See the edit.